# What factor(s) can induce the charges to the conductor as in this isolated situation?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, vacuum, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

The 2 conductors exists.

The actual diagram(not this diagram) depicts conductor with clay form but I depicted it as sphere form since I thought that sphere form can also be  congruent of clay form.

$$  C_{1} = \text{capacitance of the left conductor}  $$

$$  C_{2} = \text{capacitance of the right conductor}  $$

As the charge $Q_{1}$ is given to the green one and no charge is given to the blue one ,the below equation can be held.

$$  \frac{Q_{1} k_{e}  }{d} =V_{2}:=\text{potential of the blue conductor}  $$

Currently I can't get the following 2 statements.

In this time , the $ \pm Q  $ are induced to the both sides of the blue conductor.

Each magnitude of the induced charges is so small.

What are the meanings of the statements?

"Both" was used but which direction? left side is facing to the green conductor and the opposite side is the other side?

Seemingly there is no such tube or something which can bring charges to the blue conductor since I assume the conductors have been placed in the vacuum.

What knowledge am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula gives the potential at any point at a distance d from $Q_1$, relative to infinity.  If that charge is positive it will attract electrons to the near side of the blue sphere and leave an equal positive charge on the far side.

Comment: The statements don't imply that the blue conductor has any charge as  $Q_{1}$ is given to the green conductor.
So as far as any charge doesn't exist in blue conductor, how those charges are attracted?

Comment: Seemingly spontaneous generation of charges were occured for me.

Comment: No charge is added to $C_2$. The field from $Q_1$ causes a separation of positive and negative charges on $C_2$.